# Combination of tee and tty

Tags: shell, sudo, pipe, devices, tty

I tried the below command, I read it from a book

`sudo ls |  tee /dev/tty3a`

This command gives to me Permission denied, even with `sudo`.
Here tty is the teletypewriter, I know this already. But what is meant 3a with tty?

Comment: What do you expect that command to do?

Comment: I want to test this command

Comment: @Rahul Iam added user to dialout group, But its still shows error

Comment: @SuperKrish You then need to log out and log back in again for it to be effective. Then see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: You tested it, and it didn't work (for good reasons, IMO).  What did you intend to use that for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

Comment: Run `stat /dev/tty3a` and add the output to your original question.

Comment: You write "_even with `sudo`_". How exactly did you add `sudo` to this command? Please [edit] your question to provide this missing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of device files in `/dev` vary between Unix variants. There are a few that you'll find everywhere, such as `/dev/tty` meaning the current terminal. It seems that `/dev/tty3a` is the name of the fourth serial port¹ on some Unix variants including Solaris and SCO OpenServer. The Linux equivalent would be `/dev/ttyS3`. So `ls|tee /dev/tty3a` duplicates the output of `ls` to the fourth serial port.

If there is no device plugged into the serial port, you'll get an error (“Input/output error”). If there is no driver for the serial port, you'll get a different error (“No such device”). If the device node doesn't even exist, you'll of course get “No such file or directory”.

If the device node exists but you don't have permission to access it, you'll get the error “Access denied”. Unless you're running as root, or there is a hardware terminal plugged onto that serial port and you're logged in on that terminal, it's likely that you don't have permission to access that device.

Assuming the device is present, if you want to access it as root, you need to run the command `tee` as root, for example with

```
ls | sudo tee /dev/tty3a
```

Note that `sudo ls | tee /dev/tty3a` would not work, because that only runs `ls` as root, the command `tee` is not an argument to `sudo` and runs as the original user. In this command, the pipe is created by the original shell and the call to `sudo` constitutes the left-hand side of the pipe. If you wanted to run both `ls` and `tee` as root, you would need to write `sudo ls | sudo tee /dev/tty3a` (with the pipe creation still in the original shell). If you wanted to run both commands as root and perform the pipe setup as root, you would need to invoke a shell as root to set up the pipe: `sudo sh -c 'ls | tee /dev/tty3a'`

¹  <sub>Serial ports are numbered from 0.</sub>

Comment: See also the `write` command to write to somebody else's terminal, and `mesg` to (dis-)allow those `write`s.

Answer (score 1):

The example you found in a book show that you can write on your own and other terminals screen at the same time. Login two times on the same server and run `w`and you get something like:

```
$ w
USER  TTY    FROM   LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
joe   pts/1  :0     21:53    0.00s  0.04s  0.00s w
joe   pts/2  :0     22:38    3.00s  0.01s  0.01s /bin/bash
```

At the first console write:

```
$ seq 3 | tee /dev/pts/1
```

and you get the double output.

Then try on the same console

```
$ seq 3 | tee /dev/pts/2
```

and you get the same output on boths screens.

This could be useful if you have a lot of monitors/consoles which logged in and you want to update them from one console.